# Present information from JSON in two pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-route

I'm trying to create a webpage which reads json. I have a first page,index, that works just fine. I get correct information from json and print it out correct. But, I want to have a subpage, which have more details. To get this details.

I don't know how to take out the specific object from json and present the information on another page?

My code looks like this:

**EXAMPLE JSON**

```
{
  "Name": "foo",
  "array": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
  "boolean": true,
  "null": null,
  "number": 123,
  "object": {
    "a": "b",
    "c": "d",
    "e": "f"
  },
  "string": "Hello World"
}
```

*Lets say that i have 5 jsonobject like this. On my index-page i do ng-repeat to print them, for example, name and number. The name is a link to "more details"-page. More detail presents, for example the array.*

**ReadJson**

```
var readJSON = function($scope, $interval, $http){
    $http.get("./output/resultJSON.json").success(function(response) {
        $scope.result = response;
    })
```

**ReadMoreDetails**

```
var readDetails = function($scope, $routeParams){

};
```

**ng-route**

```
 var application = angular.module("application", ['ngRoute']);

application.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when("/index.html", {
            templateUrl: "index.html"
        })
        .when("/showTable", {
            templateUrl: "templates/resultTable.html",
            controller: "readJSON"
        })
        .when("/showMoreDetails/:id", {
            template: "templates/moreDetails.html",
            controller: "readDetails"
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo:"/showTable"});
});
```

**MyLink**

```
<div class="link" ng-click="result.Name"><a href="/showMoreDetails/{{result.Name}}">{{result.Name}}</a></div>
```

Comment: Are both these pages under same app? If yes, you can try $rootScope

Comment: You could create a service and access it from both pages

Comment: You can use a service which all your controllers take information from. Move "readJson" to a service and then address your data from the service. For example--> yourService.results.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this,

```
var readDetails = function($scope, $routeParams){
    $http.get("./output/resultJSON.json").success(function(response) {
      $scope.result = response;
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.result.length; i++) {
         if($scope.result[i].Name == $routeParams.id {
           $scope.details = $scope.result[i].array
         }

       };
    })
};
```